# Possible 'this' implementation in C++

Tags: c++, this, rvalue-reference, rvalue, lvalue

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33477809/3421515) post when i try to understand what `xvalue`, `glvalue` and `prvalue` values are.

I also intuitively think that, under the hood, `this` is passed to member function like :

`void SomeClass::func(SomeClass* this, int a, int b)`

but as stated in the answer and the standard, `this` should be `prvalue` so my assumption was wrong.

I tried to mimic `this` as `prvalue`

```
template<typename T>
T* possible_this_impl() {
    T* ref { nullptr };

    // Somehow retrieve the currently referred object

    return ref;
}

struct foo {

    int a_non_static_member_function() {
        possible_this_impl<foo>(); // Now it is a prvalue
        possible_this_impl<foo>()->x;
        possible_this_impl<foo>()->y;
    }

public:

    int x {};
    int y {};

};

int main()
{
    foo f;
    f.a_non_static_member_function();
}
```

But actually, I wonder what could be possible implementation of `this` ? Could anyone enlighten me ?

**Note:** No need very deep explanation but maybe a simple explanation could be enough.

Comment: In your sample `void SomeClass::func(SomeClass* this, int a, int b)`, `this` could be overridden. That's not possible. IMHO, (a hypothetical) `void SomeClass::func(SomeClass *const this, int a, int b)` does catch it better. Please, note: `*const` makes the pointer itself immutable but not its contents. (That's subject of whether the member function is `const` or not. For a `const` member function, it would be `void SomeClass::func(const SomeClass *const this, int a, int b)`.)

Comment: Why don't you just check out the compilers source code?

Comment: @Scheff you are right but i just write the code for demonstration so i didn't take into consideration its mutability, immutability and other properties.

Comment: @arnes I must admit I'm a bit weak concerning classification into `prvalue` and company. However, my guess: that's why `this` is considered as prvalue - it (the pointer) itself is immutable.

Comment: @Scheff My intuition is the same. It is not actually `prvalue` but compiler treats it as `prvalue`.

Comment: _I wonder what could be possible implementation of this ?_ Long time ago, when I struggled to understand the very basics of OOP and C++, (and using TurboC++ when it was still state-of-the-art) I had a look onto the generated assembly (inlined into source code). So, I saw that the object pointer (in a member function call) just was pushed to the stack together with the other arguments. One of my click-moments... ;-)

Comment: In the generated assembly, prvalues are probably indistinguishable from lvalues or xvalues. These are categories the compiler should consider in its semantical analysis (to check whether a certain access is allowed or a certain optimization is applicable).

Comment: @Scheff So you say it is not implemented like, let's say, `operator new`. Just the compiler handles it implicitly and treats `this` as `prvalue` ?

Comment: I think so. Please, remember, `this` is a keyword (in opposition to an identifier for a variable) and might be left out, i.e. is applied implicitly as well when appropriate.

Comment: `this` is a builtin functionality. It doesn't have to be otherwise implementable within the language.

Comment: I got my answer, thanks both of you, if you post as answer i can accept it.